# Energy barriers between Hadamard matrices

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, matrix-analysis

Hadamard matrices may be characterized as $n\times n$ real orthogonal matrices $U$ that achieve the lowest possible "energy" as defined by the (scaled and shifted) entry-wise 1-norm:
$$
E(U)=n^2 -\sqrt{n}\,\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n |U_{i j}|.
$$
We'll consider only those $n$ for which Hadamard matrices exist; their energy is zero.

I'm interested in the minimum energy "barrier" between distinct Hadamard matrices. Let $U_0$ and $U_1$ be distinct Hadamard matrices and $U_t$ a continuous map from the unit interval to orthogonal matrices (a "curve") with these matrices as endpoints. The energy barrier, for this curve, is the maximum over $t$ of the energy:
$$
\Delta E(U_t)=\max_t E(U_t).
$$
Finally, define $\Delta E$ as the infimum of energy barriers over all curves that join any pair of distinct Hadamard matrices.

$\Delta E$ is easily bounded above by $90^\circ$ Givens rotations (as curves) that have the effect of swapping two rows or columns of a Hadamard matrix; the maximum energy, at the halfway point, is $(2-\sqrt{2})n$. Is this bound sharp, or are there smaller barriers?

Comment: I don't understand your forumlae.  Isn't E(U) of a Hadamard matrix negative?

Comment: U is orthogonal (for example the identity matrix), so when its matrix elements have equal magnitude, that magnitude is 1/sqrt(n).

Comment: So it is orthonormal. My mind does not take orthogonal vectors and automatically normalize them.  Also, the literature I read has most Hadamard matrices have determinant size larger than 1.